# SQL Server - ALTER TABLE and INSERT in same transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, insert, alter

I am trying to add a column to a table, then insert data into it, then drop that column. I want this to be in a transaction. 
For the purpose of my question, I've simplified the problem here, in reality I am using the new column temporarily to fetch some data from another table, then I insert it into the altered table. I have the same problem with the simplified version.

After the `ALTER TABLE` statement, I have a `GO` that is required, however SSMS is telling me

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near ';'.
```

If I remove the `GO`, the insert statement fails when trying to insert into the newly added column.

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Invalid column name 'NewCol'.
```

If I run the `ALTER TABLE` statement before the `BEGIN TRAN` with the `GO` it works fine. But I need this to be in a transaction.

Any help is appreciated. Code is below:

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN

    ALTER TABLE myTable
    ADD NewCol varchar(6);
    GO

    INSERT INTO myTable (NewCol, BillingName, BillingAddress)
    SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(linkedServer, 'SELECT * FROM customer');

    ALTER TABLE myTable
    DROP COLUMN NewCol;

COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH
```

Comment: What's the use for this? Why add a column that you throw away immediately afterwards? That doesn't make sense to me. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve with that?

Comment: Why not use a temp table instead of adding and dropping columns like this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a table variable:

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN

    DECLARE @temp TABLE(NewCol <type>, BillingName <type>, BillingAddress <type>);

    INSERT INTO @temp (NewCol, BillingName, BillingAddress)
    SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(linkedServer, 'SELECT * FROM customer');

    INSERT INTO myTable
    SELECT BillingName, BillingAddress FROM @temp;

COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH
```

Comment: This is a table variable, not a temp table. Different animals, and they can't/shouldn't be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 different problems here. First is the concept of batches. GO is a "command" that is understood by SSMS (and some other tools); it is used to separate a string of text into batches. A batch is a unit of work (code) that the application (SSMS) submits to the database engine for execution. When the engine receives the batch, it will compile it first. And compilation is done for the entire batch all at once. Though your batch adds the column before it attempts to use it, the compiler does not consider your alter statements when evaluating the insert query. Hence, you get the error.

Unfortunately you cannot divide your script into multiple batches because the entire script must run within a single batch due to the logic used. To get around this, you could use dynamic sql for all of the statements following the alter statement. But that is an advanced skill and I cannot recommend it. To be honest, this approach seems flawed; I think you should re-evaluate the decisions that led you down this path. One important consideration is that error handling in pure tsql is difficult and inconsistent - even for the experienced.